# Retrieve Entity Framework DbContext from a proxy object

Tags: entity-framework

I'm using Entity framework 6 , DBcontext Database First.
I have some situations when I have a proxy object and I want to get the DBContext.
I'm using this code :

```
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Data.Objects;

namespace Sample
{
    public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<ObjectContext, MyDbContext> contexts = 
        new Dictionary<ObjectContext, MyDbContext>();

    public static MyDbContext FromObjectContext(ObjectContext context)
    {
        lock (contexts)
        {
            if (contexts.ContainsKey(context))
                return contexts[context];
            return null; 
        }
    }

    public static MyDbContext FromObject(object obj)
    {
        var field = obj.GetType().GetField("_entityWrapper");
        var wrapper = field.GetValue(obj);
        var property = wrapper.GetType().GetProperty("Context");
        var context = (ObjectContext)property.GetValue(wrapper, null);
        return FromObjectContext(context);
    }

    public MyDbContext()
    {
        lock (contexts)
            contexts[((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext] = this; 
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        lock (contexts)
            contexts.Remove(((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext);
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

}
```

}

Now , with this code I can get DBContext using this :

```
var ctx = MyDataContext.FromObject(MyObj1);
```

This code is working except one case :

If I add a new object and call SaveChanges , and after for this object try to get the DbContext , I get an error . on the line :

```
Dim wrapper = field.GetValue(obj)
```

Error :

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in myprog.exe

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

I've also found that in this case , this line return nothing :

```
var field = obj.GetType().GetField("_entityWrapper");
```

What can I do ?
Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

When you add a new object, the new object is still the original object (not an object with the proxy). You can use DbSet.Create instead of new so you have already an entity with the proxy.